# _bstr_t Not a known identifier

Tags: c++, com, bstr

I've been using this class for years and it's always "just there". I created a new project the other day and without explicitly doing anything, this class was available.

Now another new project complains it is not known. Both projects have the same #includes.

Neither project #includes comutil.h. Neither project uses the commsuppw.lib library (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6(v=vs.110).aspx). The only possibly related header included is objbase.h, which *both* projects include.

So why does one project build happily and the other doesn't? How is the one that works able to link without the needed library?

*I think this is one of those "I've been coding all day and my brain has stopped working issues" but still... what?*

Comment: Heck, I tried using `_bstr_t` in another project I created at the same time and it works just fine. Both were created as standard Windows console applications and I didn't add additional libs... why is one magically working and the other not?

Comment: The #import directive will generate a .tlh file that automatically #includes it.  Not much magic there, just not very visible.

Comment: I _think_ this might be it, that one project was explicitly importing a tlh and the other wasn't. However not all my projects do this... some where some header was including a header that included comdef.h I suppose. I'm really not a fan of #import!

Comment: Hans, thank you! I was searching for comdef.h for 30 minutes never thinking of the tlh files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed to `#include <comdef.h>`

Apparently this automagically imports the required libs.